# Shifting Parent records from child

Tags: interaction-design, tabs, grid, ux-designer, relationship

In my application, Grand parent and Parent tabs contains grid controls.

From my Child tab, i should be able to select desired parent or grand parents records without opening the Grand parent or parent tabs. By doing this my child records will change.

Please share your thoughts or ideas to solve this.

[image]

Comment: how many columns in this grid? Do you have some representative data? What other actions can be taken on the rows? Do you have batch actions? How many average records are we talking about? Provide more context and you're more likely to get some targeted and useful answers.

Comment: there can be 50+ records on parent tabs. Other cations on child tab's grid are "Adding new rows, deleting(batch action)". On average 20 records. user can edit existing child records, when accessing parent/grand parent records on child tab he/she cannot modify the parent/grand parent records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try using a batch or singular dialog (or inline editing) to change the hierarchy, and clearly display the current relationships. Use selection dependent dropdowns to see the scope of choices at all times.

In your case it seems:

- Each grandparent object has 1 to n parent objects that belong to it.
- Each parent has 1 grandparent and 1 to n child objects
- You need to change out the ownership at either level, so you need selection dependent controls to show what's available starting from the grandparent level

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKT3G8.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

#### Some caveats:

I don't know what other properties need to be displayed for any of your objects, so I put the ancestry relationship into the table columns themselves.

- Depending on the visible properties in the table, you could opt for **inline editing**. Again, I don't have your full requirements, but this could be a possible option.
- If it's important to know the ancestry without going into a detail view but there's no room in the table, you could do a hover tooltip over the name that shows `Grandparent: Melvin` > `Parent: Sara`, or a similar level of granularity.
- To navigate the hierarchy, consider hover links on ancestors in the child table that could take a user directly to the detail view, where you could see all it's descendants: again, I'm not sure if that's useful to your users.